# Getting spaces after upgrading from Indy 9 on Delphi 6 to Indy 10 on Delphi 11

Tags: xml, delphi, indy, delphi-11-alexandria, tstream

I have migrated from Delphi 6 to Delphi 11 (64 bit edition) and in that I'm using the Indy and ZLib components. I have migrated from Indy 9 to Indy 10, using the component to post API and before that I'm writing the String to a Stream via:

```pascal
var 
  XML: String; 
  stream: TStream;
begin
  ...
  stream.WriteBuffer(XML[1], Length(XML) * 2);
```

And then compressing it using the ZLib component. But when it reaches the server it includes the space for every letter in the message:

> ```xml
> < h t m l > u s e r < / h t m l >
> ```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Most likely you now have [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) instead of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) - handling a `String` like bytes was okay in Delphi 6 (which never had a 64 bit version), but now you _really_ deal with text, not bytes anymore - now text may need 2 or 4 bytes per character. In fact you don't see "_spaces_" but instead NULLs.

Comment: Yes, I have to multiply the Length with two to receive the full message and how I need to handle?

Comment: You have not understood my comment. And you have to convert your UTF-16 `XML` content to whatever encoding you want in your `stream`... but [XML also supports UTF-16 directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Encoding_detection) - you may not have understood XML, too.

Comment: Required read: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Delphi 2009, the `string` type has been a UTF-16 encoded `UnicodeString`. You are writing the raw character bytes of a `string` *as-is* to your `TStream`, hence why you need to multiply the string's length by 2 since `SizeOf(Char)` is 2 bytes.  The *spaces* you are seeing are actually byte `#$00`, as ASCII characters in UTF-16 have their high byte set to zero.

But in Delphi 6, the `string` type was a 8-bit `AnsiString` instead, and `SizeOf(Char)` was 1 byte.

To get the same behavior in Delphi 11 that you had in Delphi 6, you need to *convert* your `UnicodeString` characters into encoded bytes before writing them to your `TStream`.  The default/preferred encoding for XML is UTF-8 (but can be any other charset you choose to specify in the XML's prolog), eg:

```
var
  XML: string;
  utf8: UTF8String;
  stream: TStream;
...
utf8 := UTF8String(XML); // use UTF8Encode() in Delphi 6
stream.WriteBuffer(utf8[1], Length(utf8));
```

Alternatively, Indy has overloaded `WriteStringToStream()` functions in the `IdGlobal` unit, which have an optional `ADestEncoding` parameter, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal;

var
  XML: string;
  stream: TStream;
...
WriteStringToStream(stream, XML, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Alternatively, you can use Delphi's own `TStringStream` class instead, which has an optional `TEncoding` parameter in Delphi 2009+, eg:

```
var
  XML: string;
  stream: TStream;
...
stream := TStringStream.Create(XML, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Alternatively, simply don't use a `TStream` at all. Indy's `TIdIOHandler` class has a `DefStringEncoding` property for textual reads/writes, and its `Write(string)` and `WriteLn(string)` methods also have an optional `AByteEncoding` parameter, eg:

```
var
  XML: string;
...
Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
...
Connection.IOHandler.Write(XML);
```

or:

```
var
  XML: string;
...
Connection.IOHandler.Write(XML, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Comment: I have tried with the initial answer and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.