# How to convert the 32 bit webserver to 64 bit response

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-6

Already I had a problem with sending data using the `TIdHTTP` component in Delphi 11, and I got the solution from [Getting spaces after upgrading from Indy 9 on Delphi 6 to Indy 10 on Delphi 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76757025/).

```pascal
// sUrl - DSOAP Url
// streamRequest - Request Stream and it will send as compressed data.
// streamResponse - TStream of the response of DSOAP and it will receive as compressed.
IdHttp.Post(sUrl, streamRequest, streamResponse)
```

Now, I'm facing the problem after receiving the data. How can I read the data from the stream using Delphi 11?

Here is the code to convert the received stream to a `string`. After calling this method, I'm getting some junk value:

```pascal
var 
  xml: PChar;
  sXML: string;
  iLength: string;
  streamResponse: TStream; // Before this method, the response is decompressed using ZLib decompression Logic
begin
  iLength := streamResponse.Seek(0, 2);
  xml = strAlloc(iLength+1);
  FillChar(xml^, iLength+1, #0);
  streamResponse.Seek(0, 0);
  streamResponse.Read(xml^, iLength);
  sXML := strPas( xml );   // Getting error after calling this.
  strDispose(xml);
end;
```

This logic works fine in Delphi 6, but is getting an error while using Delphi 11.

Comment: I would bet your problem is because of the change of the string type from ANSI to Unicode between D6 and D11, not the change from 32 to 64 bits compilation!

Comment: IMHO use `stream.Position` instead of `stream.Seek`

Comment: In Delphi 6 all string is AnsiString that's meens that every char is 1-byte. In Delphi 11 default codeing is 2-byte string, thats why your code does not working in same way. As i saw in your previous solution you decode string in UTF-8 that's means that Char got variable size from 1 to 4 bytes that's why you can't just do `streamResponse.Read(xml^, iLength * sizeOf(char));` and you need to use TEncoding to convert bytes into string.

Comment: @sn_na_v You didn't need to delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765758/) just to re-ask the same question with more detail. You can edit your questions. I will repost the relevant portion of my previous comment that still applies here: "*Just as you had to make your sending code account for the migration from ANSI to Unicode, ... you likely need to account for that in your receiving code, too.*"

Comment: @sn_na_v Why not simply let `TIdHTTP` handle both the decompression and the conversion to `string` for you in one go?  If the response is compressed, you can assign a `Compressor` to `TIdHTTP` to decompress it.  And you can use an overload of `TIdHTTP.Post()` that returns a `string` instead of fills a `TStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you must to check if you decompress stream in a right way.

You can do in by saving content of stream in file and open it by any text editor.

```
streamResponse.SaveToFile('c:\temp\MyStream.txt');
```

If all is fine - convert it into string:

```
var
  sStream : TStringStream;
  sXML : string;
...      
  sStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    sStream.LoadFromStream(streamResponse);
    sXML := sStream.DataString;
  finally
    sStream.Free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: FYI, since he's already using Indy, there is a `ReadStringFromStream()` function in the `IdGlobal` unit which takes an `AByteEncoding` parameter, eg: `sXML := ReadStringFromStream(streamResponse, -1, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);`